# Is energy always uncertain?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

ΔE⋅Δt⩾ℏ/2

Does the energy time uncertainty principle imply that an object would have to stay for an infinite amount of time in a state for there to be no uncertainty in the energy of that state?

Comment: Energy eigenstates do seem to be stationary.

Comment: Nothing is infinite so everything is uncertain. Not just energy, but every observable value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, that is what it implies.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, that is correct. Although things could be thought to have difinite energy for practical purposes.